# How to do an IF statement based on the value of a MySQL table cell?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I do an if statement based on the value of a mysql table cell. For example, I have a table of people with a column called marital_status. This column has one of two values: yes or no. But this doesn't work:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT marital_status FROM people WHERE first_name = 'John'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

     $maritalStatus = $row['marital_status'];

}

if ($maritalStatus == "yes") {
   echo "This person is married.";
}
else {
   echo "This person is NOT married.";
}
```

$maritalStatus == "yes" doesn't return as true even though that is exactly the value in that cell.

Comment: What do you get if you do "echo $maritalStatus" instead of the if?

Comment: I get the actual value: "Yes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to work on each line of data returned by your SQL query, you should place your condition inside the `while` loop -- which iterates over the lines returned by the excution of the query :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT marital_status FROM people WHERE first_name = 'John'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $maritalStatus = $row['marital_status'];
    if ($maritalStatus == "yes") {
       echo "This person is married.";
    }
    else {
       echo "This person is NOT married.";
    }
}
```

If this doesn't help, it could be useful to check :

- If the query actually returns results
- If those results are actually what you think they are.

This can be done using [`var_dump`](http://www.php.net/var_dump), to dump the content of a variable. For example, in your situation, you could use :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT marital_status FROM people WHERE first_name = 'John'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    var_dump($row);     // Will display the content of $row
}
```

---

As a sidenote, you said in a comment that echoing $maritalStatus gets you **"`Yes`"**.

**If there is a `Y` in uppercase in your database, that's the reason why your code fails** : you are testing for "`yes`" in lowercase.

In PHP, using the `==` operator for string comparisons, **uppercase letters and lowercase letters are considered as different characters**.

If you want to compare in a case-insensitive manner, you'll have to either :

- Convert all strings to the same case *(upper or lower, up to you to choose)*

  - see [`strtolower`](http://www.php.net/strtolower) or [`strtoupper`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)
  - or [`mb_strtolower`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) / [`mb_strtoupper`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php) if using a multi-byte encoding, such as UTF-8
- Use a case-insensitive comparison function, such as [`strcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/strcasecmp)

Comment: Moving it inside the while loop doesn't help. Var dump reveals this:

array(1) { ["marital_status"]=>  string(3) "Yes" }

Comment: I see I wrote yes with a lower case y in my original question. But in my actual code the cases are correct. Still no luck.

Comment: @Susan : If you have `"Yes"` with an **uppercase** `Y` in your database, and are testing it against `"yes"` in **lowercase** in your code, that's why your code fails : **uppercase and lowercase letters are not the same character** -- I've edited my answer with some additionnal informations *(much better than a comment ^^ )*

Comment: Oh ;-( ;;; can you edit your question to give us the actual real code you are using ? *(just in case there is another typo somewhere ;-) )*

Comment: I'm so stupid, the problem was in my actual code I didn't put an echo before the "This person is married". Next time I will copy paste my code here instead of writing it from scratch :p

Comment: huhu :-D ;;; yeah, you should always post your real code, as by re-typing it you will most likely not do the same mistakes ;-) ;;; glad you found out what was causing the problem !

Answer (score 1):

You should move your `if` block inside the `while` loop.
And make sure you account for letters case.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT marital_status FROM people WHERE first_name = 'John'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

     $maritalStatus = strtolower($row['marital_status']);

    if ($maritalStatus == "yes") {
      echo "This person is married.";
    }
    else {
      echo "This person is NOT married.";
    }
}
```